# Построить обратную матрицу методом Гаусса

Tags: python, математика, матрицы

Делаю код для расчета такой матрицы. Он состоит из двух частей - прямой ход, на котором получаю  треугольную матрицу с единицами на главной диагонали и нулями ниже. На втором этапе двигаюсь "снизу-вверх", преобразуя элементы, лежащие выше главной диагонали к нулю, тем самым добиваясь единичной матрицы в результате.

Спасибо: ранее здесь подсказали с первой частью - массив дает треугольную матрицу. Однако пытаясь выполнить обратный ход, ловлю ошибку, свидетельствующую о проблемах с размерностью: shapes (1,6) and (1,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

```
import numpy as np
def inverse_matrix(matrix_origin):
    """
    Функция получает на вход матрицу, затем добавляет к ней единичную матрицу, 
    проводит элементарные преобразования по строкам с первоначальной, добиваясь получения слева единичной матрицы.
    В этом случае справа окажется матрица, которая является обратной к заданнй первоначально 
    """
    # Склеиваем 2 матрицы: слева - первоначальная, справа - единичная
    m = np.hstack((matrix_origin, 
                np.matrix(np.diag([1.0 for i in range(matrix_origin.shape[0])]))))
#     n = matrix_origin.shape[1]
    n = m.shape[1]
    
    for nrow, row in enumerate(m):
        # nrow равен номеру строки
        # row содержит саму строку матрицы
        divider = row[nrow] # диагональный элемент
        # делим на диагональный элемент:
        row /= divider
        # теперь вычитаем приведённую строку из всех нижележащих строк:
        for lower_row in m[nrow+1:]:
            factor = lower_row[nrow] # элемент строки в колонке nrow
            lower_row -= factor*row # вычитаем, чтобы получить ноль в колонке nrow

# обратный ход:
    for k in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        for row_ in range(k - 1, -1, -1):
            if m[row_, k]:
                # 1) Все элементы выше главной диагонали делаем равными нулю
                m[row_, :] -= m[k, :] * m[row_, k]
    return np.hsplit(m, n // 2)[1]
    
            
matrix = np.array([[3.8, 6.7, -1.2], 
                   [6.4, 1.3, -2.7], 
                   [2.4, -4.5, 3.5]])

inverse_matrix(np.copy(matrix))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! P.S. Вероятнее всего, в процессе создания минимального примера вы сами поймёте в чём ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас несколько ошибок в коде.

1. Вы конструируете правую часть как `np.matrix`, поэтому после `np.hstack` вы получаете тоже объект типа `np.matrix`. Это очень специальный вид массивов. В частности, итератор `m` возвращает не одномерные строки чисел, а двумерные массивы формы `(1,6)`. В результате `row[nrow]` оказывается не числом, а одномерным массивом.

   В `numpy` есть специальная функция для построения единичной матрицы: `np.eye(n)` строит единичную матрицу размером `n x n`. Поэтому вам лучше конструировать `m` как `m = np.hstack((matrix_origin, np.eye(len(matrix_origin)))`
2. Вы инициализировали `n` как число колонок в `m`: `m = m.shape[1]`. Но тогда вот эта строчка неверна: `for row_ in range(k - 1, -1, -1)` - у вас нет строк с номерами 5,4,3. Если `n` определяет число строк, то нужно присваивать вот так: `n = m.shape[0]`
3. Но в таком случае сломается ваш код выделения правой части `np.hsplit(m, n // 2)[1]`. Я предлагаю использовать индексирование вместо hsplit: `m[:, n:].copy()` есть двумерный массив, каждая строка которого есть строка из `m` начиная с элемента с номером `n`, то есть элементы №№ 3,4 и 5. Как раз правая часть матрицы `m`. Метод `copy()` вызывается для того, чтобы не держать указатель на `m`, в противном случае `m` будет висеть в памяти до тех пор, пока "жив" указатель на результат функции `inverse_matrix`

После исправления этих ошибок получится что-то вроде

```
def inverse_matrix(matrix_origin):
    """
    Функция получает на вход матрицу, затем добавляет к ней единичную матрицу, 
    проводит элементарные преобразования по строкам с первоначальной, добиваясь получения слева единичной матрицы.
    В этом случае справа окажется матрица, которая является обратной к заданнй первоначально 
    """
    # Склеиваем 2 матрицы: слева - первоначальная, справа - единичная
    n = matrix_origin.shape[0]
    m = np.hstack((matrix_origin, np.eye(n)))
    
    for nrow, row in enumerate(m):
        # nrow равен номеру строки
        # row содержит саму строку матрицы
        divider = row[nrow] # диагональный элемент
        # делим на диагональный элемент:
        row /= divider
        # теперь вычитаем приведённую строку из всех нижележащих строк:
        for lower_row in m[nrow+1:]:
            factor = lower_row[nrow] # элемент строки в колонке nrow
            lower_row -= factor*row # вычитаем, чтобы получить ноль в колонке nrow
    # обратный ход:
    for k in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        for row_ in range(k - 1, -1, -1):
            if m[row_, k]:
                # 1) Все элементы выше главной диагонали делаем равными нулю
                m[row_, :] -= m[k, :] * m[row_, k]
    return m[:,n:].copy()
```

Результат инвертирования вашей матрицы

```
array([[ 0.04128819,  0.09805945,  0.08980182],
       [ 0.15689513, -0.08790039, -0.01401625],
       [ 0.1734104 , -0.18025555,  0.206115  ]])
```

Я добавил [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1271321/invert_gauss.ipynb) со своим вариантом, он быстрее на 10-15% за счёт выбора операций индексирования.